# Restore damaged boot sector

Tags: mac, mount, dmg-image

After a series of unfortunate events, I have a clone of my laptop's hard drive as a .dmg file (created using `dd`).  The dmg was built using the `noerror` option, which means that significant portions of this dmg and NULLed out.  (for more information on `dd`, see this: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050302225659382)

Because the first several megabytes of this dmg file are zeroed out, the dmg refuses to mount.  Disk Utility can't repair it, so I'm wondering if there's any way to copy some other disk's boot sector into my dmg so that it will mount.

I realize that this is probably a risky thing to do, but if I can just get 1 folder off of this dmg, it would be worth my time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If created with `dd` this is not a dmg, but an img file. Try renaming it to img and mount in the Finder by opening it. If there is any usable information about partitions or volumes it should mount. If it doesn't your're out of luck and need look into recovery software like ProSoft's DataRescue.